# Concatenate two columns if not null with knockout.js binding

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mvc

I am using Knockout.js in a MVC razor project to bind a table column with FirstName and LastName

```
<td><label class='required' data-bind="text: FirstName + ' ' + LastName" /><td/>
```

It concatenates but when one field is empty, it will display null in the output.

Like:

Jone Smith
Null Smith
Jone Null
Null Null

How can I remove this null?

Comment: Try using it like function `data-bind="text: FirstName() + ' ' + LastName()"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a computed property:

```
viewmodel.FullName = ko.computed(function(){
     if (viewmodel.FirstName && viewmodel.LastName)
          return viewmodel.FirstName + ' ' + viewmodel.LastName
     else if(viewmodel.FirstName)
          return viewmodel.FirstName;
     else if (viewmodel.LastName)
          return viewmodel.LastName;  
     else
          return '';
});
```

And then update your binding like this:

```
<td><label class='required' data-bind="text: FullName" /><td/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say check if there is value in the string: like so
`if(FirstName)`or `FirstName.length > 0`
and If so you could set `FirstName = '';`

Answer (score 0):

A computed with less if else cases than Kenneths, and that can be reused

```
function joinComputed() {
    var parts = arguments;
    return ko.computed(function() {        
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(ko.utils.arrayMap(parts, function(part) {
            return ko.unwrap(part)
        }), function(part) {
            return part;
        }).join(" ");
    })
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6yLrjc5y/